# Device benchmarking: How many videos can a device play at the same time?

Tags: android

My device can display 3 videos simultaneously without problem. But I suppose not all the devices my app will be used on (api 21+) have the cpu cores and RAM to do that.

What would be a good way to determine at runtime how many videos the device can handle?

The best I can come up with at the moment is to always allow 3 videos and adjust the video resolution I request from the server by looking at the screen width: High-resolution devices tend to have better hardware

Answer (score 0):

*High-resolution devices tend to have better hardware* - Correct but not always the case. I would not depend on this alone.

*But I suppose not all the devices my app will be used on (api 21+) have the cpu cores and RAM to do that.* - You could  retrieve the hardware spec of the device and determine it on that; if you're comfortable enough that this is enough to determine if the device can run 3+ video or not, along with your resolution check.

Benchmark to see how one video playing is affecting the hardware e.g. using 0.7gb of ram, cpu usage at 47% etc.  and from that, you can have a rough estimate to determine further.